# Date Picker with Multilingual support in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, date, multilingual

Anyone have any experience on doing a popup date picker 
with multilingual support, based on the culture itself automatically?

I do try to do it but I am failed to do it. Anyone have any resources that can do it? I am mainly doing for two languages which is `en-US` and `zh-TW`. Thanks.

Comment: have a look at [here](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) and also [here](http://code.runnable.com/UdTuotHbZoQNAABq/adding-a-date-picker-to-an-input-form-field-using-jquery)

Comment: @nadeem i did but its not pop up..

<script>
        $(function () {
            $("#txtDate").datepicker();
        });
  </script>


                            <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>

Comment: what do you mean by `popup` here, what exactly do you want. Also, is the calendar is coming or not ? show us the code in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @nadeem sorry... here is the jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/x5a7bk0o/

Comment: See the answer below which I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not adding the `Jquery` and `CSS` reference, that's why you are not able to see the Jquery Calendar.

Try the below code:-

*Jquery and CSS reference*

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Also, you must call the `selector`i.e `ID` for it to work

```
$(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });
```

See the [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x5a7bk0o/1/)

Comment: @LstPatrick: You have not added the `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>` the reference. See the js fiddle left hand side, you will see `3` reference added.

Comment: I just seen it, sorry. do you have any idea make it multilingual base on the current culture?

Comment: `multilingual base on the current culture?` what does these mean, do you have any example related to it or any links ??

Comment: example like when user choose English, then the page will show all English. the culture of the system will change to en-US, if choose Mandarin will change to zh-TW. does the calander can track base on the culture and show the language? but for sure all thlte character are required to pre define. just wonder how to plug in in this calander. do you have any idea?